# Duda algoritmo diferenciar datos comparando matrices PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

Veamos. Tengo dos bases de datos, una MySQL y otra MS Access. Accedo a ambas con PHP. Los datos de MySQL los saco de la siguiente forma:

```
    $queryWS= "SELECT IdPedido, idarticulo FROM pedidos";
    $lecturaWS=mysqli_query($conWebService, $queryWS);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($lecturaWS)){
        $datosPK_WS[]=$row; //Array numérico
    }
```

Esto me devuelve un array numérico (detalle que creo que importa para lo que haré luego).

Los datos de la tabla de MS Access los saco de la siguiente forma:

```
 $queryMS= "SELECT IdPedido, idarticulo FROM pedidos";
    $lecturaMS=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $queryMS);

    while($row=odbc_fetch_array($lecturaMS)){
        $datosPK_MS[]=$row; //Array asociativo
    }
```

Esto devuelve un array asociativo. Pues bien, ahora quiero mediante la comparación de su PK (que es IdPedido), quiero ver cuándo en la tabla de MySQL hay un PK que no hay en la tabla del MS Access, para proceder a hacer un INSERT. Pues bien, estoy atascado con la comparación entre tablas. Aquí el código:

```
    $DBchanges=array();

    for ($a=0; $a < count($datosPK_WS); $a++) { 
        for ($b=0; $b < count($datosPK_WS[$a]) ; $b++) { 
            if($datosPK_WS[$a][$b] !== $datosPK_MS[$a][$b]){
                array_push($DBchanges, $datosPK_WS[$a][$b]) ;
                
            }
        }
    }

var_dump ($DBchanges);
```

Pues esto me da error, Undefined offset 0 y undefined offset 1. Además del error, teóricamente no me debería meter nada en el array ya que la info de ambas bases de datos es la misma y, sin embargo, me está metiendo todos los datos en el array. No sé dónde está el fallo. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es que leas ambas consultas de la misma forma, te sugiero que sea con arreglo asociativo, usando [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Genera los resultados de ambas consultas como arreglos asociativos `IdPedido => idarticulo`; de esta forma, no es necesario recorrer el segundo arreglo para saber si contiene o no el `IdPedido`, basta con [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset):

```
// Inicializar resultados para ambas consultas
$datosPK_WS = [];
$datosPK_MS = [];

$queryWS= "SELECT IdPedido, idarticulo FROM pedidos";
$lecturaWS=mysqli_query($conWebService, $queryWS);
// Leer como arreglo asociativo
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($lecturaWS)){
    // Crear elemento por cada pedido
    $datosPK_WS[$row['IdPedido']] = $row['idarticulo'];
}

$queryMS= "SELECT IdPedido, idarticulo FROM pedidos";
$lecturaMS=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $queryMS);
// Leer como arreglo asociativo
while($row=odbc_fetch_array($lecturaMS)){
    // Crear elemento por cada pedido
    $datosPK_MS[$row['IdPedido']] = $row['idarticulo'];
}

$DBchanges = [];

// Recorrer arreglo de resultados MySQL
foreach($datosPK_WS as $idPedido = $idarticulo) {
    // Si el pedido no existe en resultados de MS Access
    if(!isset($datosPK_MS[$idPedido])) {
        // Agregar al arreglo
        $DBchanges[] = ['IdPedido' => $idPedido, 'idarticulo' => $idarticulo];
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Solo vas a obtener un artículo por cada pedido y, cuando vayas a "sincronizar", debes leer el pedido completo de una base de datos para insertarlo en la otra.

Comment: Una respuesta muy completa. Muchas gracias. Sólo dos dudas: $datosPK_MS[$row['IdPedido']] = $row['idarticulo'];
} ¿Qué haces exactamente en esta línea de código? Crear el array asociativo ¿? Porque $datosPK_MS tiene luego todos los IdPedido=>idarticulo o sólo tiene uno y lo va sobreescribiendo ¿? Y con esta línea de código qué hago exactamente foreach($datosPK_WS as $idPedido = $idarticulo) ¿?  ¿Recorrer el array de datosPK_WS y decirle que por cada idPedido me saque su idarticulo? Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @Sergio, exactamente, en la nota final te comento precisamente eso, solo hay un artículo por pedido, porque así fue como formulaste la pregunta: _mediante la comparación de su PK (que es IdPedido)_